# Why I am getting an error when I try to get a row from the database in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg

I need to get a row from database with a needed parameter. I'm using asycpg to work with Postgresql
Here is my code for this:

```
row = await connection.fetchrow('SELECT * FROM ' + self.game_name +' WHERE full_url = $1', full_url)
```

When I launch my script, I get this error:

[image]

What is the problem? P.S I'm using python3

Comment: `await` is only valid inside a coroutine function (`async` function). And these two keywords were introduced with python 3.5, so you have to use python 3.5 or later.

Comment: I tried to use str() but nothing has changed

Comment: Haken, thank you a lot, the problem was in miss of async before function name. I need to be more attentive